# How to join summary table and data table to preserver row level data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Table A contains data for every employee. Table B contains summarised data. I want to join Table A with Table B to get Table C, which retains the structure of Table A.

input table A below:

| office | job |
| --- | --- |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | SM |
| B | M |
| B | M |
| B | C |
| B | C |
| B | C |
| B | C |
| B | SAC |
| B | SAC |
| B | SAC |
| B | AC |
| B | AC |

The above table contains the office location and the role.

input table B below:

| office | jobs | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | SAC,AC | 5 |

We have to combine the job role of count is less than 5. For the position total count is 7(>5) so,we don't combine that with anything but job roles M has to be combined with C to make the count 6(>5) and SAC has to be combined with AC to make the count>5.this is just the context as these tables are already present as input table.

required output Table C below:

| office | job | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | SM | 7 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | M,C | 6 |
| B | SAC, AC | 5 |
| B | SAC, AC | 5 |
| B | SAC, AC | 5 |
| B | SAC, AC | 5 |
| B | SAC, AC | 5 |

Aim is to combine row level data with aggregated data. I tried using like operator but failed.

I tried using split but the jobs(Table B) column can have more than 2-3 roles. I also tried using like operator but failed as substrings match with other strings

Comment: Which DBMS are you are using? sql server <> oracle.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: I must admit, the *real* problem looks like you have a denormalised design. You should *not* be storing delimited data in your database.

Comment: You also need to be consistent... this question doesn't have spaces between the jobs, your other question does, which is it?

Comment: you need to provide a minimal reproducible example in the form of a dbfiddle showing the provided solutions not working. Because based on your sample data they do.

Comment: I have tested both solutions provided here and they both provide the requested results. Unfortunately DBFiddle seems to be down so I can't post a working fiddle. My guess is that you have spaces in your table b data... which you can easily replace out using the 'replace' function.

Comment: HI Dale, sincere apologies from my side. seems that I missed the space after the comma and it was causing all the trouble. I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those questions where "solution" probably lands you into more problems than if you don't do it altogether.

```sql
with tablea as (
    select *
    from 
    (
    VALUES  (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'SM')
    ,   (N'B', N'M')
    ,   (N'B', N'M')
    ,   (N'B', N'C')
    ,   (N'B', N'C')
    ,   (N'B', N'C')
    ,   (N'B', N'C')
    ,   (N'B', N'SAC')
    ,   (N'B', N'SAC')
    ,   (N'B', N'SAC')
    ,   (N'B', N'AC')
    ,   (N'B', N'AC')
) t (office,job)
)
, tableB as (
    select *
    from 
     (
    VALUES  (N'B', N'SM', 7)
    ,   (N'B', N'M,C', 6)
    ,   (N'B', N'SAC,AC', 5)
) t (office,jobs,Count)
)
select b.office, b.jobs, b.Count
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
     ON b.office = a.office
     and    ',' + b.jobs + ',' like '%,' + a.job + ',%'
```

Should output what you want,

`',' + b.jobs + ',' like '%,' + a.job + ',%'` is the key join which matches containing job from tableA in a list of jobs in tableB.

Comment: Not sure why it would fail, did you see that you have to add commas in the LIKE otherwise it would indeed match too much.

Comment: sincere apologies. I missed the space after coma which is present in the real data. I have marked your answer as a solution. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways. One is:

```
select tableB.*
from tableA
inner join tableB on tableA.office=tableB.office and
  ','+tableB.job+',' like '%,'+tableA.job+',%';
```

Another one is using only the tableB and a join on a Tally table. I am not adding a sample, because I don't know the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One way is get output as per your required as a Table C using below query

```
SELECT
     A.office
    ,A.job
     ,B.jobs
FROM
    Your_Table_A AS A
LEFT JOIN
    Your_Table_B AS B ON A.job =
      CASE WHEN A.job = B.Jobs THEN B.Jobs
             WHEN (SELECT COUNT(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(B.Jobs,',') WHERE TRIM(value) = A.job ) > 0 THEN A.job
      END
ORDER BY
    A.office, A.job;
```